Dynamically redirect one C# method to another at runtime in .NET 8
I have been using the following method to redirect a C# method into another at runtime:
public class Injection
    {        
        
        public static void install(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);

            unsafe
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    int* inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
                    int* tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;

                    //Console.WriteLine("\nVersion x86 Debug\n");
                    byte* injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    byte* tarInst = (byte*)*tar;

                    int* injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    int* tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
                }
                else
                {

                    long* inj = (long*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer()+1;
                    long* tar = (long*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer()+1;

                    //Console.WriteLine("\nVersion x64 Debug\n");
                    byte* injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    byte* tarInst = (byte*)*tar;


                    int* injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    int* tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
                }
            }
        }
    }

The code works in .NET 6, it was copied from the answers to the question Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method? but it causes a memory access violation in .NET 8: Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. I suspect this to be caused by this breaking change in .NET 8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/reflection/8.0/function-pointer-reflection.
I need help to update this method for .NET 8 as it's used in many places in our code base and I haven't found a suitable alternative, the closest I have found is Lib.Harmony but it doesn't work for me.
I have tried changing the code offset (+5) used in the current version.

I don't want to be "that guy" but I think you should take one more step back on your problem and ask why you're trying to do this. This feels like an antipattern for this strongly typed language. Have you tried using a factory pattern or even just fuction/actions to do what you're trying to do?

I appreciate the advice, but I have a lot of duplicate test code that relies on this single method, replacing would require changing the tests' logic which sounds like too much work. I agree that this is not a clean nor maintainable way and intend to change it in the long run.

Why? Why?! Any rationale? Why would you want to do such things? Do you really want to get some working answer, not explaining your motivation?
